# How to solve: Error installing pandas WinError[123]

Tags: python, pandas, pip

When I install pandas using "`pip install pandas`".

It stucks and after a while it throws this Error:

> ERROR:  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
> command: 'C:\Users\Tomas Kloucek\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\python.exe'
> 'C:\Program
> Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.240.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\site-packages\pip'
> install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix 'C:\Users\Tomas
> Kloucek\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-5func91g\overlay'
> --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- setuptools wheel 'Cython>=0.29.21,<3'
> 'numpy==1.15.4; python_version=='"'"'3.6'"'"' and
> platform_system!='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy==1.15.4;
> python_version=='"'"'3.7'"'"' and platform_system!='"'"'AIX'"'"''
> 'numpy==1.17.3; python_version>='"'"'3.8'"'"' and
> platform_system!='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy==1.16.0;
> python_version=='"'"'3.6'"'"' and platform_system=='"'"'AIX'"'"''
> 'numpy==1.16.0; python_version=='"'"'3.7'"'"' and
> platform_system=='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy==1.17.3;
> python_version>='"'"'3.8'"'"' and platform_system=='"'"'AIX'"'"''
> cwd: None
> Complete output (25 lines):
> Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version == "3.6" and platform_system != "AIX"' don't match your environment
> Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version == "3.7" and platform_system != "AIX"' don't match your environment
> Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version == "3.6" and platform_system == "AIX"' don't match your environment
> Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version == "3.7" and platform_system == "AIX"' don't match your environment
> Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version >= "3.8" and platform_system == "AIX"' don't match your environment
> Collecting setuptools
> Using cached setuptools-50.3.0-py3-none-any.whl (785 kB)
> Collecting wheel
> Using cached wheel-0.35.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (33 kB)
> Collecting Cython<3,>=0.29.21
> Using cached Cython-0.29.21-py2.py3-none-any.whl (974 kB)
> Collecting numpy==1.17.3
> Using cached numpy-1.17.3.zip (6.4 MB)
> Using legacy 'setup.py install' for numpy, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
> Installing collected packages: setuptools, wheel, Cython, numpy
> Running setup.py install for numpy: started
> Running setup.py install for numpy: still running...
> Running setup.py install for numpy: still running...
> Running setup.py install for numpy: still running...
> Running setup.py install for numpy: still running...
> Running setup.py install for numpy: still running...
> Running setup.py install for numpy: still running...
> Running setup.py install for numpy: finished with status 'done'
> ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [WinError 123] Název souboru či adresáře nebo jmenovka svazku je
> nesprávná: '"C:'
>
> ```
>   ----------------------------------------
> ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'C:\Users\Tomas Kloucek\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\python.exe'
> ```
>
> 'C:\Program
> Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.240.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\site-packages\pip'
> install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix 'C:\Users\Tomas
> Kloucek\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-5func91g\overlay'
> --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- setuptools wheel 'Cython>=0.29.21,<3'
> 'numpy==1.15.4; python_version=='"'"'3.6'"'"' and
> platform_system!='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy==1.15.4;
> python_version=='"'"'3.7'"'"' and platform_system!='"'"'AIX'"'"''
> 'numpy==1.17.3; python_version>='"'"'3.8'"'"' and
> platform_system!='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy==1.16.0;
> python_version=='"'"'3.6'"'"' and platform_system=='"'"'AIX'"'"''
> 'numpy==1.16.0; python_version=='"'"'3.7'"'"' and
> platform_system=='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy==1.17.3;
> python_version>='"'"'3.8'"'"' and platf``orm_system=='"'"'AIX'"'"''
> Check the logs for full command output.

Any suggestions would be appreciated

Comment: What is the version of Python? Can you share the whole error message plz?

Comment: I'm using python 3.9

Comment: Most probably, Pandas wiheel is not supported in Python 3.9 version yet. You can try with pipwin. First install pipwin with pip install pipwin, then pipwin install pandas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look in to this question [I am trying to install pillow using 'pip'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64354059/)

In short, As far as i see a lot of the packages are not supporting Python 3.9 yet. I think your best bet is to uninstall Python 3.9 and install Python 3.8.6. If you want you could try to download the pillow wheels from [here](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#matplotlib) and try to install it may it will work.

The following command might also help.

```
pip install pipwin
pipwin install <package name>
```

Comment: I am trying to follow up, did this solve your issue, or did it not help you at all?

Comment: *install (typo - written intstall)

Comment: @NotSoShabby thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Most probably, pandas wheel is not supported in Python 3.9 version yet. If this is the situation, you can try with `pipwin`.

First, install `pipwin` with

`pip install pipwin`

then

`pipwin install pandas`.

NB: pipwin behaves just like pip

Comment: C:\Users\Tomas Kloucek>pipwin install pandas
'pipwin' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Answer (score 0):

I installed all dependencies one by one and then tried pip install pandas again and it just worked.