# I am trying to install pillow using 'pip'

Tags: python, pip

I'm trying to install Pillow library and it fails in the setup.
After the download completed I get a long list of errors.

```
 Complete output (174 lines):
    C:\Users\Yair\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-b852i6zy\pillow\setup.py:42: RuntimeWarning: Pillow 7.2.0 does not support Python 3.9 and does not provide prebuilt Windows binaries. We do not recommend building from source on Windows.
      warnings.warn(
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\BdfFontFile.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\BlpImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\BmpImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\BufrStubImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\ContainerIO.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\CurImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\DcxImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\DdsImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\EpsImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\ExifTags.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\features.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\FitsStubImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\FliImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\FontFile.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\FpxImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\FtexImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\GbrImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\GdImageFile.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\GifImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\GimpGradientFile.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\GimpPaletteFile.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\GribStubImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\Hdf5StubImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\IcnsImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\IcoImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\Image.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\ImageChops.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\ImageCms.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\ImageColor.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\ImageDraw.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\ImageDraw2.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\ImageEnhance.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\ImageFile.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\ImageFilter.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\ImageFont.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\ImageGrab.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\ImageMath.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\ImageMode.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\ImageMorph.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\ImageOps.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\ImagePalette.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\ImagePath.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\ImageQt.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\ImageSequence.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\ImageShow.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\ImageStat.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\ImageTk.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\ImageTransform.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\ImageWin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\ImImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\ImtImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\IptcImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\Jpeg2KImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\JpegImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\JpegPresets.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\McIdasImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\MicImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\MpegImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\MpoImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\MspImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\PaletteFile.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\PalmImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\PcdImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\PcfFontFile.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\PcxImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\PdfImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\PdfParser.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\PixarImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\PngImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\PpmImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\PsdImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\PSDraw.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\PyAccess.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\SgiImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\SpiderImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\SunImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\TarIO.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\TgaImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\TiffImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\TiffTags.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\WalImageFile.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\WebPImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\WmfImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\XbmImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\XpmImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\XVThumbImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\_binary.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\_tkinter_finder.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\_util.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\_version.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\__main__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    running egg_info
    writing src\Pillow.egg-info\PKG-INFO
    writing dependency_links to src\Pillow.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
    writing top-level names to src\Pillow.egg-info\top_level.txt
    reading manifest file 'src\Pillow.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
    reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
    warning: no files found matching '*.c'
    warning: no files found matching '*.h'
    warning: no files found matching '*.sh'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching '.appveyor.yml'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching '.coveragerc'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching '.editorconfig'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching '.readthedocs.yml'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching 'codecov.yml'
    warning: no previously-included files matching '.git*' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.so' found anywhere 
    in distribution
    no previously-included directories found matching '.ci'
    writing manifest file 'src\Pillow.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
    running build_ext
```

The headers or library files could not be found for zlib,
a required dependency when compiling Pillow from source.

Please see the install instructions at:
https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.ht

Comment: *Pillow 7.2.0 does not support Python 3.9 and does not provide prebuilt Windows binaries. We do not recommend building from source on Windows.* Downgrade to python 3.8 or wait until Pillow supports python 3.9 on Windows (which doesn't seem to be the case yet)

Comment: try `pip install Pillow==8.0`

Comment: Pillow 8.0.0 supporting Python 3.9 is out now! https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/releasenotes/8.0.0.html

Answer (score 0):

getting a latest update of python is not always too good, especially for the module 
There are some module that does not support latest python
However , there is `pip3` 
May you try `pip3 install pillow`

> **I'm Currently**
>
> python 3.7.9

[image: An Example of using pip3 if you do not know yet]

Answer (score 0):

Python 3.9 is not even released for 10 days yet. As far as i see a lot of the packages are not supporting Python 3.9 yet. I think your best bet is to uninstall Python 3.9 and install Python 3.8.6. If you want you could try to download the pillow wheels from [here](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#matplotlib) and try to install it may it will work.

The following command might also help.

```
pip intstall pipwin
pipwin install <package name>
```

Comment: Pillow 8.0.0 supporting Python 3.9 is out now! https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/releasenotes/8.0.0.html

Comment: I am trying to follow up, did this solve your issue, or did it not help you at all?